# Recreate banner, tikz intersections

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I am trying to recreate the following image

[image]

After a bit of fiddling I was able to create the following

[image]

Where the code can be found at the bottom. While I am happy with the result, I am not happy with my approach / code.

Is there a cleaner / better way to create the image in question? In particular

- Is there any way to avoid guessing the semicircles?
- Could a better result be achieved with polynomials instead?
- Is there a better way to do the intersection between the rectangle and circles? The whole part with `\tkzDrawPolygon[color=dark,fill=dark,line width = 0cm](A,E,F,D)` feels wrong and dirty.
- Can the rectangle be created any easier?
- Can one use any overlays or something to make sure the tikz solution is accurate? Now I imported the image into Geogebra and fiddled around until I achieved something "sensible". However, except the colors it is not particularly accurate.

[image]

## Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{light}{HTML}{c48fcd}
\definecolor{medium}{HTML}{a757b2}
\definecolor{dark}{HTML}{9637a0}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmax=18.72, ymax=3.2]
    \tkzClip
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} \tkzDefPoint(18.72,0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(18.72,3.2){C}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,3.2){D}
    \tkzDefPoint(10,0){E}
    \tkzDefPoint(10,3.2){F}

    \tkzDefPoint(6.96, 16.5){S1}
    \tkzDefPoint(8.02, 13.68){S2}

    \tkzDefPoint(14.00028,1.24159){R1}
    \tkzDefPoint(14.76398,1.2677){R2}

    \tkzDrawPolygon[color=medium,fill=medium,line width = 0cm](A,B,C,D)

    \tkzDrawCircle[color=light, fill=light](S2,R2)
    \tkzDrawCircle[color=dark, fill=dark](S1,R1)    

    \tkzDrawPolygon[color=dark,fill=dark,line width = 0cm](A,E,F,D)

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: bad idea to use `tkz-euclide` to do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a much shorter code that reproduces your screen shot rather well IMHO. I also address your question to fit it precisely in a page. (`\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` is used to show that it works.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\definecolor{light}{HTML}{c48fcd}
\definecolor{medium}{HTML}{a757b2}
\definecolor{dark}{HTML}{9637a0}
\begin{document}
\noindent%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myscale}{\textwidth/18.85cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt},scale=\myscale]
 \fill[dark]  (0,0) rectangle (18.85,3.25);
 \fill[light] (10,0) to[out=14,in=-140] (17.32,3.25)--
  (17.6,3.25) to[out=-140,in=15] (11.7,0) -- cycle;
 \fill[medium] (17.6,3.25) to[out=-140,in=15] (11.7,0) -| (18.85,3.25) -- cycle;
 \node[anchor=south west,text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries,scale=3*\myscale] at (0.5,0.75){Prove};
 \node[anchor=south east,text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries,scale=2*\myscale] at (18.3,0.4)
 {24.05.2019};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for your questions:

- Is there any way to avoid guessing the semicircles? -- You need to have an idea what the path should be. Circles are not a bad choice IMHO.
- Could a better result be achieved with polynomials instead? -- I do not see how polynomials may help but there are many ways to draw such arcs.
- Is there a better way to do the intersection between the rectangle and circles? The whole part with \tkzDrawPolygoncolor=dark,fill=dark,line width = 0cm feels wrong and dirty. -- Yes, see my code below. You do not need any of the `tkz-euclide` stuff and can shorten the code considerably.
- Can the rectangle be created any easier? -- Yes, there is the `rectangle` path construction which is used below.
- Can one use any overlays or something to make sure the tikz solution
  is accurate? Now I imported the image into Geogebra and fiddled
  around until I achieved something "sensible". However, except the
  colors it is not particularly accurate. -- "Accurate" w.r.t. what? If you have a clear prescription for the arcs, you can achieve very good accuracy.

The following contains a much shorter code. Note also that `tikz` loads `xcolor`, so there is no need to load `color`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\definecolor{light}{HTML}{c48fcd}
\definecolor{medium}{HTML}{a757b2}
\definecolor{dark}{HTML}{9637a0}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[dark] (0,0) rectangle (18.72,3.2);
    \clip (6,0) rectangle (18.72,3.2);
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rone}{veclen(7.04,15.35)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rtwo}{veclen(6.74,12.41)}
    \fill[light,even odd rule] (6.9, 16.5) circle[radius={\rone*1cm}]
    (8.02, 13.68) circle[radius={\rtwo*1cm}];
    \fill[medium,even odd rule]     (8.02, 13.68) circle[radius={\rtwo*1cm}]
    (8.02, 13.68) circle[radius={2*\rtwo*1cm}];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you give me a hint for the prescription how this image is obtained, it will be possible to make it very accurate.

Comment: Awesome solution! Is there an easy way to scale this to fit on a standard pagewidth? I am not able to give much context for the image unfortunately as I obtained it from a pdf. It is used for the cover image for the exams at my school.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar I added a simple way to adjust the size to the text width. If you want to adjust it to another length, replace `\textwidth` in `\pgfmathsetmacro{\myscale}{\textwidth/18.85cm}` by this length.